# Computing probability one program is faster than another

Tags: poisson-distribution

So I often have the situation where I want to compare the runtime of two computer processes. Even when measuring only user+system time (as opposed to wall clock time) there is a random element in the measured time. I'm going to suppose that this randomness is poisson distributed (task switches and interrupts from random events on the computer system).

My hypothesis is that a single program with identical input will run in some amount of time which is composed of a constant amount of time to execute the instructions and some random amount of time generated by one or more poisson process.

So let's simplify for the moment and assume that there's one poisson process and each time it happens it accounts for the same amount of time. We don't know lambda, nor t(lambda), the time associated with it. I can, however, run the same program on the same input many many times.

How can I estimate what the constant part of the run time is?
How can I estimate lambda and t(lambda)?

The deeper issue is...

If I have two programs that do the same thing and I want to estimate the probability that one runs faster than the other how would I do this? It seems that blindly applying the normal distribution could be problematic. The random part is (I believe) poisson; but before applying the poisson distribution I'd have to factor out the constant portion.

Comment: Wait, you're assuming time - a continuous variable - is *Poisson distributed* - that is, distributed as a discrete variable? How does that make sense? If you're saying that switches and interrupts occur randomly, you might argue that the *number* of them that happen are Poisson, but that wouldn't make the *time* they take Poisson, and it wouldn't make the total time for your process Poisson.

Comment: Well, on a computer computer time is discrete, I'm assuming that there are random events; each of which accounts for some time, say t(e), and the total time of the program is C + n*t(e).

Comment: To state it another way it's similar to modeling the time spent on the phone by agents at a call center, where the average time spent on a call is meaningful (the variance would only account for a small portion of the total time) and the calls coming in to the call center are a poisson process.

Alternatively I could claim that time is discretized  by the hyperfine structure transitions of the cesium atom.

Comment: "on a computer computer time is discrete" - well strictly, yes, all measurements are only finitely precise. But Poisson is for *counts* of events, not their duration. The time between events in a Poisson process *does not have a Poisson distribution*. It has an exponential distribution. If your process is being interrupted by many events, though, its the distribution of the time taken by their process, not the inter-event time, that you'd need to sum up to figure out what additional time your process takes.

Comment: I think we are in agreement here, I assume that (to rough approximation) that the time for each event is constant; so that the number of events is total extra time taken divided by the length of time for the events. 

The primary source I've measured is the time to process interrupts for network traffic. If I shut down the network connection and run a program the variance in run times is very small compared to when I turn the network adapter on. The variance is even larger (as is the total time) if I'm throwing a lot of network traffic at that particular machine.

Comment: that is, the total extra time is some integer multiple of the time to process an event.

Comment: Hmm. Unless the number of events is very few or the standard deviation of the times is very small indeed, a small amount of variation will still smear the discreteness out into the adjacent (also 'smeared' by variation) times.

Answer (score 2):

You may model the running times $X_1,\dots,X_n$ of the program  as conditionally independent and identically distributed, given $M=\mu$ and $\Lambda=\lambda$, with density
$$
  f_{X_1\mid M,\Lambda}(x_1\mid \mu,\lambda) = \lambda\,e^{-\lambda(x_1-\mu)} I_{(\mu,\infty)}(x_1) \, .
$$
The likelihood of this translated exponential model is
$$
  L_x(\mu,\lambda)=\lambda^n \, e^{-\lambda\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) - n\mu\right)} I_{(0,x_{(1)})}(\mu) \, .
$$
As a first attempt, I would try a Bayesian analysis with a Jeffreys-like prior $f_{M,\Lambda}(\mu,\lambda)\propto 1/\lambda$. One goal is to estimate $M$ by $\mathbb{E}[M\mid X=x]$. To sample from the posterior, I would try a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm proposing the next $M$ as $\mathrm{U}[0,x_{(1)}]$, and the next $\Lambda$ from a gamma distribution with expectation equal to the previous value and a tiny variance. With a working sampler, it is easy to compute the estimate and a posterior credible interval for $M$. It is not difficult to extend this analysis to a second program; with the necessary additions to the notation, the natural way to compare both programs is to compute
$P(M<M'\mid X=x,X'=x')$. If this probability is near zero or near one, you can claim that one of the programs is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It'll take some time for me to digest that; but I'll be making a run at it this week.

Comment: Fine. If you have any doubts, just ask.